# JPA date not equal to Oracle date after save

Tags: oracle, hibernate, jpa

I have the following oracle table..

```
create table post (id number(10,0) not null, text varchar2(255 char), title varchar2(255 char), update_date date, version number(10,0), primary key (id));
```

My entity looks something like this..

```
@Entity
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class Post {

    @Id Integer id;
    String title;
    String text;
    @LastModifiedDate @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP) Date updateDate;
    @Version Integer version;
    ....
}
```

The repository is simply this...

```
public interface PostRepository extends JpaRepository<Post, Integer>{

}
```

The following test fails...

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class PostRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired protected JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    @Autowired PostRepository postRepo;

    private static final Integer TEST_POST_ID = -1;
    private static final String TEST_TEXT = "This is the text.";

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        String insertPostSql = "insert into POST (ID, TITLE, TEXT, UPDATE_DATE, VERSION) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
        jdbcTemplate.update(insertPostSql, new Object[]{TEST_POST_ID, "Title 1.", TEST_TEXT, new Date(), 0});
    }

    @After
    public void teardown() {
        String deletePostSql = "delete from POST where ID = ?";
        jdbcTemplate.update(deletePostSql, new Object[]{TEST_POST_ID});
    }   

    @Test
    public void testUpdateA() throws Exception {
        Post post = postRepo.findById(TEST_POST_ID).get();
        post.setTitle(TEST_TEXT+" Amendment.");
        Post updatedPost = postRepo.save(post);
        assertNotEquals(post.getVersion(), updatedPost.getVersion());
        Post updatedPost2 = postRepo.save(updatedPost);
        assertEquals(updatedPost.getVersion(), updatedPost2.getVersion());
    }

}
```

The second update to the entity is persisted to the database even though nothing has changed. If I change the type of the update date column in the database to TIMESTAMP, the test succeeds. Unfortunately I can't do this, is there something else I can do as the date in the returned instance from the save call is not equal to the date in the database according to JPA dirty check.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve this I ended up implementing my own @PreUpdate method instead of using @LastModifiedDate and within this method I set the update date to an instance of timestamp and set the nano seconds to 0.

```
@PreUpdate
public void onPreUpdate(Post post){
    Timestamp ts = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()); ts.setNanos(0);
    post.setUpdateDate(ts);     
}
```